# Why is my newly created method not appearing in a different class that has a reference to the class to which the method belongs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, dll

I have 2 projects in my asp.net C# solution. One project is 'AeS.PIMS_Education_2275.IL' and the other is 'AeS.PIMS_Education_2275.PL'. I just created a new method in a class called 'PIMS_Education_IL_2275' belonging to 'AeS.PIMS_Education_2275.IL'. The project 'AeS.PIMS_Education_2275.PL' has a reference to 'AeS.PIMS_Education_2275.IL', but when I create an object of the class 'PIMS_Education_IL_2275' inside the class 'PIMS_Education_2275' of 'AeS.PIMS_Education_2275.PL' and try to access the methods in it, I am able  to access all methods apart from the newly created method. What might be wrong here ? Below are the code snippets:

Class - AeS.PIMS_Education_2275.IL

```
namespace AeS.PIMS_EducationDetails_IL_2275
{
    public class PIMS_Education_IL_2275
    {
        public DataSet ValidateEducationDiscipline()    //newly created method
        {}
    }
}
```

Class - PIMS_Education_2275

```
using AeS.PIMS_EducationDetails_IL_2275;

namespace AeS.PIMS_Education_2275.PL
{
    public partial class PIMS_Education_2275
    {
         public bool FormValidation()
         {
              PIMS_Education_IL_2275 o = new PIMS_Education_IL_2275();  //Creating an object
              o.ValidateEducationDiscipline();    //Not able to call the method here
         }
    }
}
```

Additional information - I had just one project in the solution initially and then added the second one in which I created a new method.

Screen shots of dependencies:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What error(s) do you get?

Comment: @JasperKent, when I try to type the name of the method, it says that the class PIMS_Education_IL_2275.PIMS_Education_IL_2275 does not contain a definition for 'ValidateEducationDiscipline' and no extension method accepting first argument of type....'

Comment: Is it a "direct" reference to the project or via nuget package?

Comment: Is your AeS.PIMS_Education_2275.IL project building successfully?

Comment: @Fildor, it is a direct reference.

Comment: @JasperKent, the project is building successfully, however I am not able to debug even its already existing methods.

Comment: @JasperKent - Additional information - I had just one project in the solution initially and then added the second one in which I created a new method.

Comment: Maybe post a screenshot of your dependencies?

Comment: @JasperKent, added screenshots.

Comment: Puzzling. If you double click on AeS.PIMS_Education_2275.IL in the dependencies list, you should be able to see the contents in Object Explorer. You can drill down and see whether the method is actually there. I suspect this will simply confirm what we already know (that it's missing) but it's worth a look.

Comment: @JasperKent, the method does not appear when I view the contents of the assembly AeS.PIMS_Education_2275.IL, but it appears under the project file for AeS.PIMS_Education_2275.IL.

Comment: Very weird. Can't think of much else to do. Things like Rebuild All, restart Visual Studio, remove and re-add the reference may shake things up.

Comment: @JasperKent, I think this is because of adding an existing project to the solution. But I am not sure what to do about this.

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem to add an existing project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Use the project reference instead of direct reference. 
2) verify the build order of the solution. The project AeS.PIMS_Education_2275.IL should build first and then AeS.PIMS_Education_2275.PL